# You didn't provide an API key. You need to provide your API key in an Authorization header using Bearer auth.... (Chatgpt api)

Tags: javascript, node.js, openai-api

I am testing the chatgpt api by using html input elements to submit a prompt but keep coming across this error whenever I submit via my button.

"You didn't provide an API key. You need to provide your API key in an Authorization header using Bearer auth (i.e. Authorization: Bearer YOUR_KEY), or as the password field (with blank username) if you're accessing the API from your browser and are prompted for a username and password. You can obtain an API key from [https://platform.openai.com/account/api-keys."](https://platform.openai.com/account/api-keys.%22)

index.js file

```
 import {createRequire} from "module";
 import {config} from "dotenv";
 config()

 import OpenAI from "openai";

 const openai = new OpenAI({
 apiKey: process.env.OPENAI_API_KEY,
 });

 const require = createRequire(import.meta.url)

 const express = require("express");
 const app = express();

 app.use("/", express.static("public"));

 const getResponse = async (text) =>{
    const response = await openai.completions.create({
       model: "text-davinci-003",
       prompt: text,
       temperature: 1,
       max_tokens: 256,
       });

     }
  app.post("https://api.openai.com/v1/chat/completions", async (req, res) => {
    if (!req.body.promptText) {
       res.status(400).send("Bad Request");
    } else {
       const promptText = req.body.promptText;
       try {
          const response = await getResponse(promptText);
          res.status(200).send(response.choices[0].text);
    } catch (error) {
        console.error(error);
        res.status(500).send("Internal Server Error");
       }
     }
 });

  app.listen(3000)
```

index.html file

```
    <textarea id="text-prompt" name="promptText" placeholder="type in prompt here" style="width: 300px; height: 150px;"></textarea>
   <button type="button" id="btn-upload">Upload</button>
   <textarea id="resultsText" placeholder="Answer goes in here" style="width: 300px; height: 150px;"></textarea>
     <script>
       const textPrompt = document.getElementById("text-prompt");
       const btnUpload = document.getElementById("btn-upload");
       const resultText = document.getElementById("resultsText");

       btnUpload.addEventListener("click", () => {
         const formData = new FormData();
         formData.append("promptText", textPrompt.value);

         fetch("https://api.openai.com/v1/chat/completions", {
             method: "POST",
             body: formData
         })
         .then(response => response.text())
         .then(promptAnswer => {
             resultText.value = promptAnswer;
         })
         .catch(error => {
             console.error(error);
             resultText.value = "Error occurred.";
         });
     });
```

I've looked through the documentation and my api key is formated like it suggests. Im not sure whats causing this error.

Comment: your code that posts `app.post("https://api.openai.com/v1/chat/completions"` has no authorization header at all, in fact, it's a POST with no body, which is unusual - perhaps you read the documentation wrong - which documentation did you refer to?

Comment: oh, wait, I see the issue - what does your front end (browser) code do? `app.post("https://api.openai.com/v1/chat/completions"` in your backend doesn't do what you think it does

Comment: I created a textarea element and then used that to collect the prompt and submit it with a button. Heres what documentation I was refering to: https://platform.openai.com/docs/api-reference/chat/create

Comment: I repeat, what does your front end (browser) code do? Please show the relevant code  (at a guess it'll be either a fetch or an XMLHttpRquest) that you think is calling your backend, but is in fact calling the AI API directly and therefore has no authorisation header

Comment: I've included it now.

Comment: Your front-end `fetch` call does not send any headers, including the required authentication header, so: _read the error_, it even tells you what that header should look like =) (but if that's not detailed enough, search the web for how to add an authorization header using fetch. _Lots_ of results, including from here on Stackoverflow)

Comment: just as I suspected, your backend code is irrelevant since your front end doesn't even call it